# IndexOutOfBoundsException in AdapterList

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I tried to organize work with dynamic data in the recently presented `AdapterList` component. As a test, i placed the data list in the state of the parent component and added a button that would reduce the length of the initial list by one with every click.

```
val (data, setData) = state { testFilms }

Column {
    Button(onClick = {
        setData(testFilms.dropLast(1))
    }) {
        Text("Change")
    }

    AdapterList(
        data,
        modifier = LayoutPadding(5.dp) + LayoutHeight.Fill + LayoutWidth.Fill
    ) { film ->
        FilmItemView(
            film = film,
            selectFilmAction = selectFilmAction,
            logger = logger
        )
    }
}
```

But instead of the expected result, I got the following error when recomposing the `AdapterList`:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at androidx.ui.foundation.ListState$composeChildForDataIndex$3$1.invoke(AdapterList.kt:448)
    at androidx.ui.foundation.ListState$composeChildForDataIndex$3$1.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
    at androidx.compose.ObserveKt.Observe(Observe.kt:37)
    at androidx.ui.foundation.ListState$composeChildForDataIndex$3.invoke(Unknown Source:11)
    at androidx.ui.foundation.ListState$composeChildForDataIndex$3.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
    at androidx.compose.Recomposer$recompose$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:61)
    at androidx.compose.Recomposer$recompose$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:19)
    at androidx.compose.ViewComposerKt.runWithCurrent(ViewComposer.kt:387)
    at androidx.compose.Recomposer.recompose(Recomposer.kt:51)
    at androidx.compose.Recomposer.access$recompose(Recomposer.kt:19)
    at androidx.compose.Recomposer$Companion.recompose$compose_runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:42)
    at androidx.compose.Composition.compose(Composition.kt:67)
    at androidx.compose.Composition.compose(Composition.kt:59)
    at androidx.compose.Compose$subcomposeInto$1.invoke(Compose.kt:253)
    at androidx.compose.Compose$subcomposeInto$1.invoke(Compose.kt:23)
    at androidx.compose.ViewComposerKt.runWithComposing(ViewComposer.kt:397)
    at androidx.compose.Compose.subcomposeInto(Compose.kt:252)
    at androidx.ui.foundation.ListState.composeChildForDataIndex-N7Qnm20(AdapterList.kt:447)
    at androidx.ui.foundation.ListState.recomposeAllChildren(AdapterList.kt:358)
    at androidx.ui.foundation.ListState.recomposeIfAttached(AdapterList.kt:352)
    at androidx.ui.foundation.AdapterListKt.AdapterList(AdapterList.kt:486)
    at com.gitlab.andrewkuryan.lab1.view.FilmListViewKt$FilmList$1$2$invoke$1.invoke(FilmListView.kt:174)
    at com.gitlab.andrewkuryan.lab1.view.FilmListViewKt$FilmList$1$2$invoke$1.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
    at androidx.compose.ObserveKt.Observe(Observe.kt:37)
    at com.gitlab.andrewkuryan.lab1.view.FilmListViewKt$FilmList$1$2.invoke(Unknown Source:20)
    at com.gitlab.andrewkuryan.lab1.view.FilmListViewKt$FilmList$1$2.invoke(Unknown Source:3)
```

Does anyone know any ways to work with dynamic data with this component?

Comment: This looks like a bug in AdapterList, I'll look into this a bit more soon.  I think I see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are up to date with **dev06 Jetpack Compose** you have two ways to do it:

- Your `List<Any>` must be "compose aware" and the current one available for that is `ModelList<Any>`
- You can create a model using `@Model` tag as those change the state, and your `@Compososable` function will be aware (using a `MutableList`)

**Example Code:**

```
fun addLogic(modelList: ModelList<MyModel>) {
  modelList.add(MyModel("Smith John", 10))
}

class MyModel(var name: String, var index: Int)

@Composable
fun RecycledList() { // Any name you want
  val modelList<MyModel> = modelListOf()
  var counter = 0

  addLogic(modelList)

  modelList.add(MyModel("John Doe", 99))

  MaterialTheme {
    Column {
      Container(height = 70.dp) {
         Align(alignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Button(onClick = { 
               modelList.add(MyModel("John Smith", counter++))
               // Any other logic you want
            }) {
               Text("ADD ITEM")
            }
         }
      }
      AdapterList(data = modelList) { item ->
         Center {
            Text("Hello ${item.name} - Index: ${item.index}")
         }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

[image: AdapterList]

While testing `AdapterList`, I noticed `IndexOutOfBoundsException` while removing values but no issues while adding. I'll update my answer when I get that response.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug ([issue 153195921](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153195921)), and it will be fixed in an upcoming release by [this patch](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1282253).

From a quick look, your code should work with that patch, although I can't test it from the example.  It's pretty similar to the test case in the patch, though.